# Value of type 'NSPersistentStore' can never be nil, comparison isn't allowed

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, nspersistentstore

```
let managedModel:NSManagedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModelFromBundles(nil)!


        var storeCoordinator:NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: managedModel)

        if storeCoordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil) != nil{
            if error != nil{
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                abort()
            }
        }
```

How i can fix it in latest swift2 syntax?
Thanks

> Value of type 'NSPersistentStore' can never be nil, comparison isn't
>   allowed
>   Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

[image]

Comment: You are using Swift 1.x syntax where a function returned an optional. In Swift 2 that function does not return nil in case of error, it will throw. You need to use try/catch as per the error

Comment: The easiest way to find out the proper syntax is to create a new project with Core Data enabled.

Comment: Paulw11. Can you tell me in answer how i can use try/catch?  
Thanks

Comment: Paulw11. this is ok?  
`do {
             try storeCoordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil)
                    print(error!.localizedDescription)
                    abort()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i handle it with Swift 2 :

```
let managedModel:NSManagedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModelFromBundles(nil)!
var storeCoordinator:NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: managedModel)

do {
    try storeCoordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error!.localizedDescription)
    abort()
}
```